# Are there any school that teaches in Arabic in Indonesia?

Tags: education, indonesia

I am an Arab expat in Indonesia (Jakarta) and my kids were born in Indonesia and are being raised there as well, I only speak to them in Arabic to make it their mother tongue because it will be almost impossible for them to learn it at older age but they are still not fluent in Arabic so far. My eldest will reach school age in two years and I was wondering if there are schools that teach in Arabic in Indonesia?

At least when the time comes for us to move back home they won't have problems joining a school back home.

Comment: I am not sure if there is any school that teaches every subject in Arabic, but I think Islamic schools (SD Islam) do teach Arabic as a subject.

Comment: Since you are the father would fathertongue not be more appropriate ;)

Comment: I know that here in Malang (East Java) you can even do some university degrees in Arabic.

Comment: Gontor in Ponorogo Indonesia, East Java. It is mandatory that all teachers speak fluent Fusha and student learn to become exceptional too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After a bit search, I was lucky to find a school that teaches fully in Arabic just like any school back home. All subjects are in Arabic and some English and teachers are native speakers as well. The school is called [Alharamain Saudi Academy](http://www.sacaja.net/) and it is administered by the Saudi Embassy in Jakarta. Also, they do accept any Arab not only Saudis and they have courses to teach Arabic as well (real Arabic not the one that is taught in Indonesian schools).